# SQL Server - Inserting a specific set of rows from one table to another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table called table_one. (7 Mil) rows

I want to insert 0 - 1 Mil on a new table (table_two) and then insert 1Mil one - 2mil to the same table.

```
SET ROWCOUNT 1000000
```

How can this be achieved? Is there a way to specify range of rows to be inserted?

Comment: Do you have an `ID` or a `DateTime` column or something that you can use for paging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [row_number](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
;with cte as (
   select 
      *, 
      row_number() over(order by some_field ) as rn
   from table_one
)
insert into table_two ( fields )
  select fields from cte
   where rn < 1000000
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the start and end IDs in your old table, you can do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO NewTable (...)
SELECT ... FROM OldTable
WHERE OldTableID BETWEEN @StartID AND @EndID
```

If you don't already have a useful ID, use **danihp**'s solution using [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a range of ids, you can generate them using row_number():

```
with toinsert (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by NULL order by <whatever>) as rownum
    from OldTable
)
insert into NewTable(...)
    select ... from toinsert
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in getting exact number of rows, you might employ [TOP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx):

```
insert into Table2
select top 1000000 *
  from Table1
 order by ... ID? or newid() if you want random rows.
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off exporting the entire table in [bulk import format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175937.aspx), [splitting](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/usplit.htm) it as a text file, then [bulk importing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) the seven or so pieces into the several tables.

Of course there may be keys in the original table that make it possible to do with SQL INSERT operations, but this requires information not provided in the Question posted.